# Number of trainable parameters in Convolution models (Keras)

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, convolution, keras

I am using keras to implement a cnn model.

```
         cnn = Sequential()

         cnn.add(Conv1D(2,kernel_size=10,strides=10, padding="same",activation="sigmoid",input_shape=(Dimension_of_input,1)))
         cnn.add(Conv1D(2,kernel_size=10,strides=10, padding="same",activation="sigmoid"))
         cnn.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))      
         cnn.add(Flatten())
         cnn.add(Dropout(dropout))
         cnn.add(Dense(number_of_classes, activation="softmax"))
```

I am new to cnn. I noticed that when I increase the number of conv layers, the number of trainable parameters decreases.  How is the number of trainable parameters computed and why it decreases when adding new conv1 layers ??

Answer (score 6):

According to the code, that's probably because you're using a stride of 10.

For instance, say your input image is 100*100, then after the first convolution layer the size of the feature map will be 10*10, after the second convolution layer it will be only 1*1.

If you are using one convolution layer, the number of parameters in the `Dense` layer would be 10*10*2*`number_of_classes`. If there're two convolution layers, the number of parameters in the `Dense` layer would be 1*1*2*`number_of_classes`, which is much smaller.